# Get-ChildItem -Recurse don't work recursive

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm trying create a powershell script to handle files from a directory, but when try use `-recurse` param, I move entire folder instead only files.

```
    # where $source = C:\Files
    # and my folder 'Files' have two subfolders '001' and '002' with files inside
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter * |
    ForEach-Object {

        # Get the current date
        $date = (Get-Date).ToString();

        # Add to log file
        Add-Content -Path $log " $date - The file $_ was moved from $source to $target";

        # Show on cmdlet
        Write-Host " $date - O arquivo $_ foi transferido de $source para $target";

        # Move items
        Move-Item $_.FullName $target;
    }
```

When I try this command `Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse ...` on cmdlet, works right.

help-me please

Comment: Hi, can post the returned error message

Comment: Don't have error message just move the folders 001 and 002. But what I want is move the files inside them

Comment: What version of powershell? using the * filter tells it "Get everything including folders". The way you tell it "Only include files" is different (or there are at least different options) depending on your powersherll version.

Comment: I'm beginner yet on powershell and using filter was the way what I found on web, but if have other way, please tell me.

Version 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [EBGreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358/ebgreen) pointed out, you are enumerating folders and files. To filter it in version 2, you'd do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter * | 
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object {

        # Get the current date
        $date = (Get-Date).ToString();

        # Add to log file
        Add-Content -Path $log " $date - The file $_ was moved from $source to $target";

        # Show on cmdlet
        Write-Host " $date - O arquivo $_ foi transferido de $source para $target";

        # Move items
        Move-Item $_.FullName $target;
    }
```

The `.PSIsContainer` property returns true when the item is a container (a folder) as opposed to a leaf (a file).

In PowerShell v3 and higher you could just do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Directory -Recurse -Filter *
```

Comment: Thank you and everybody for save my day